# Jackson XML Mapper with element and sub element with same name

Tags: java, xml, jackson, unmarshalling

There are some similar posts, but not quite the same.  This issue I am having is that the XML has an additionalProperties element inside an additionalProperties element.

```
<contractingPacket>
    .....
    <additionalProperties>
      <additionalProperties>
        <key>producerRequest.transaction.transactionType.typeCode</key>
        <value>BCRECNTRCT</value>
      </additionalProperties>
      <additionalProperties>
        <key>businessAddrName</key>
        <value>Mid Dallas Insurance Agency and Central Insurance</value>
      </additionalProperties>
    <additionalProperties>
    .....
<contractingPacket>
```

This causes a problem with the Jackson XML Mapper.  From what I can tell, each element in the xml must have a corresponding static class inside the a main class, which would be ContractingPacket.  Something like this:

```
class ContractingPacket{
   private static .....
   private static AdditionalProperties
   private static AdditionalProperties
   private static .....

}
```

The problem is that you cannot have two classes in the same file with the same name.  I have tried many different things.  None of them have panned out.  There must be some way of doing this.  Ideas?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically 2 options:

1. If the number of sub-elements are fixed at 2, you can have a class for the outer element and another class for the 2 inner elements.

   ```java
   class ContractingPacket {
       private .....

       @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "additionalProperties")
       private AdditionalPropertiesWrapper wrapper;

       private .....
   }
   class AdditionalPropertiesWrapper {
       @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "additionalProperties")
       private AdditionalProperties property1;

       @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "additionalProperties")
       private AdditionalProperties property2;
   }
   class AdditionalProperties {
       private String key;

       private String value;
   }
   ```
2. Use a `List`:

   ```java
   class ContractingPacket {
       private .....

       @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localname = "additionalProperties")
       @JacksonXmlProperty(localname = "additionalProperties")
       private List<AdditionalProperties> additionalProperties;

       private .....
   }
   class AdditionalProperties {
       private String key;

       private String value;
   }
   ```

I would recommend option 2.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to up-vote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points.